# How do I turn an address into long and lat?(google colab/ Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="My App")
#tries fetch address from geopy
location = geolocator.geocode(df2['address'])        
#append lat/long to column using dataframe location
df2.loc['lat'] = location.latitude
df2.loc['long'] = location.longitude

#catches exception for the case where no value is returned
#appends null value to column
df2.loc['lat'] = ""
df2.loc['long'] = ""

df2.head()
```

Here is the code that I tried using ^^^

[image: CSV File Sample]

```
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="My App")
location = geolocator.geocode("33000 N KINGSHIGHWAY BLVD, St.Louis" )
print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
```

This Code above worked when I picked only one address. But ofc I want it to run without me giving it a specific address.

Comment: You are passing an entire pandas series to `geolocator.geocode`.  That API only accepts one address at a time.  You will need to use something like `apply` to get a callback, once for each element of the column.

Comment: How would I loop that?

Comment: `apply` does the looping.  It calls the callback once for each row.  However, since you need to return TWO values, I'm not sure that works.  See below.

Comment: You can absolutely return multiple values with `apply`, see my answer @TimRoberts

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_lat_long(address):
    try:
        x = geolocator.geocode(address)
        return x.latitude, x.longitude
    except:
        return np.nan, np.nan

df[['latitude', 'longitude']] = df.apply(lambda x: get_lat_long(x.address), axis=1, result_type='expand')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                               address   latitude  longitude
0  33000 N KINGSHIGHWAY BLVD, St.Louis  38.649933 -90.263803
```

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response, I'm currently running the code but I have over 100,000 data points. Could this code handle that amount of data?

Comment: No, that's way more that is allowed by Nominatim's terms of service and they'll definitely and rightfully block you. If you want to do that many, I'd look into one of the paid services.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, because I don't want to install the package, but this is the kind of thing you need:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="My App")
lat, lon = [], []
for addr in df2['address'].tolist():
    location = geolocator.geocode(addr) 
    lat.append( location.latitude )
    lon.append( location.longitude )

df2['latitude'] = np.array(lat)
df2['longitude'] = np.array(lon)
```

Or:

```
locs = [geolocator.geocode(addr) for addr in df2['address'].tolist()]
locs = np.array(locs)
df2['latitide'] = locs[:,0]
df2['longitude'] = locs[:,1]
```

Comment: Its giving me an Attribute error at lat.append(location.latitude).                                                   "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude'"                                                           I had the same error for my code.

Comment: @jacksojo that means that there was no coordinate pair returned by the geocoder. you need to guard for that yourself

Comment: Here is what I tried, geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="myApp")

for i in fulldf.index:
    try:
        #tries fetch address from geopy
        location = geolocator.geocode(fulldf['address'][i])
        
        #append lat/long to column using dataframe location
        fulldf.loc[i,'lat'] = location.latitude
        fulldf.loc[i,'long'] = location.longitude
    except:
        #catches exception for the case where no value is returned
        #appends null value to column
        fulldf.loc[i,'lat'] = ""
        fulldf.loc[i,'long'] = ""
Still not working

Comment: "Still not working" does not say anything.  What does happen?